# client server exchange information

Tags: php

I'm writing a web interface in php to a machine.
My prog reads some ini files, adjusts them to key/values and present the user pages with actual values.

The user is then ready to change the values and when done I write a 2nd file with updated values.

The machine keeps on checking for my files, when it finds one it loads it, deletes it and writes his own files (the ones I read).

I can't figure out a way to inform the user that the values have been accepted, processed and are now "in production".

I tried to use a `while(file_exists(path)) {empty loop}` in the page called by the action tag of the form. The idea was to reload the calling page (which instanciates the objects and thus with new values) when the file disappears. Does not work. I think that the "action" page will only be displayed once the script has finished (the file has been deleted).

Comment: Not sure the question is clear. What's wrong with processing the input and file re-writes server-side, then echoing a message once the .ini files have been updated and initialized?

Comment: More or less what I need. But the question is: When and how do I know that the files have been processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you'll need to use a function that returns a value based on whether the script has successfully done what you asked it to do. So you could test for the existence/last-modified date of the .ini file to confirm it was recently updated (or simply use an 'or die("specific error message")' clause after writing the file.
 The same holds for re-running the .ini files so that you know they were re-run and are current - I'd advise using the return-value approach since you'll need to inform users if the scripts failed, rather than confronting them with an ugly php error message.